# Template variable return type for a class function

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to create a class for interpreting various bitmap types (for instance 24bit rgb or 16bit monochrome.. whatever). I'm not very good with templates so maybe somebody can tell me why this is giving me a pile of errors?

```
    enum PixelOptions {
        I8, I16, I32, I64, F32, F64
    };

    template <PixelOptions T>
    class BitmapInterpreter {
        uint32_t Width;
        uint32_t Height;
        void* Data;

    public:
        BitmapInterpreter(uint32_t Width, uint32_t Height, void* Data) {
            this->Width = Width;
            this->Height = Height;
            this->Data = Data;
        }


        uint8_t* Pixel<I8>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        uint16_t* Pixel<I16>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        uint32_t* Pixel<I32>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
            return nullptr;
        }
    };
```

the functions are just placeholders. Basically I want it to return a variable type pointer calculated from x and y, based on how it was declared. I thought adding < template option > to functions would do it but the compiler is simply saying "missing ; before <" right after defining the first of Pixel functions.

EDIT: PS! the template parameter has to be something I can store in a variable such as enum (why I don't just use template type)

Comment: "based on how it was declared" So how do you go from the declaration of X and Y to the return type? As posted, X and Y are always of type `const uint32_t`. Where's the dependency?

Comment: I mean if i do "BitmapInterpreter<I8> banana(10, 10, pData); BitmapInterpreter<I16> orange(10, 10, pData);" then if i call banana.Pixel(1, 0) i get pData+1 and if i call orange.Pixel(1, 0) i get pData+2

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question itself, rather than explain it in comments. It's a pain to post code in comments, and a pain to read it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the return type depend on the non-type template parameter `Pixel T`. One example is to create a helper class for this purpose:

```
template <PixelOptions T>
struct RetType;

template <>
struct RetType<I8>
{
 using type = uint8_t;
};

///More specializations go here.
```

And change your original method to:

```
typename RetType<T>::type* Pixel(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
            return nullptr;
        }
```

Comment: I don't follow the logic behind that but it works, this time for real!

Comment: The only part of the signature of `BitmapInterpreter::Pixel` that depends on `T` is the return type, you can express that dependence on `T` using the template class `RetType`. This allows a more succinct signature of `Pixel` now.

Answer (score 0):

You may specialize the method, something like:

```
template <PixelOptions T> struct PixelType;

template <> struct PixelType<I8> {
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template <> struct PixelType<I16> {
    using type = uint8_t;
};

template <> struct PixelType<I32> {
    using type = uint16_t;
};

template <PixelOptions T> class BitmapInterpreter
{
    uint32_t Width;
    uint32_t Height;
    void* Data;

public:
    BitmapInterpreter(uint32_t Width, uint32_t Height, void* Data)
    {
        this->Width = Width;
        this->Height = Height;
        this->Data = Data;
    }

    typename PixelType<T>::type* Pixel(const uint32_t& X, const uint32_t& Y);
};
template <> typename PixelType<I8>::type* BitmapInterpreter<I8>::Pixel(const uint32_t& X, const uint32_t& Y)
{
    return nullptr;
}
template <> typename PixelType<I16>::type* BitmapInterpreter<I16>::Pixel(const uint32_t& X, const uint32_t& Y)
{
    return nullptr;
}
template <> typename PixelType<I32>::type* BitmapInterpreter<I32>::Pixel(const uint32_t& X, const uint32_t& Y)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: great, that works! EDIT: nope hang on, I only get Pixel return type as uint8_t* no matter how i declare the interpreter.

Comment: @user81993: oups, don't see that you have different return type, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You have templated methods `Pixel<>` without declaring them being templates. I guess what you want to do is something like:

```
enum PixelOptions {
    I8, I16, I32, I64, F32, F64
};

// No need for template here, nothing else than one method is templated
class BitmapInterpreter {
    uint32_t Width;
    uint32_t Height;
    void* Data;

public:
    BitmapInterpreter(uint32_t Width, uint32_t Height, void* Data) {
        this->Width = Width;
        this->Height = Height;
        this->Data = Data;
    }


    // Declaring there is such a method
    template <PixelOptions T>
    uint8_t* Pixel(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y);
};

// Defining specific versions of the method
template <>
uint8_t* BitmapInterpreter::Pixel<I8>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
    return nullptr;
}
template <>
uint16_t* BitmapInterpreter::Pixel<I16>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
    return nullptr;
}
template <>
uint32_t* BitmapInterpreter::Pixel<I32>(const uint32_t &X, const uint32_t &Y) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Note that this still does not produce valid code because the return type is different in each case. You would need to template that as well.